# Trouble understanding sockets.io room

Tags: javascript, sockets

I am trying to configure a 1v1 game with multiple rooms on my server with sockets.io. When the user create a room, a random alphanumeric identifier of 5 letters is generated and the user joins the room.

```
 function handleNewGame() {
        let roomName = makeid(5);
        client.join(roomName);
  }
```

Then another user is supposed to join with the room name. The room name is taken from a  tag inside the html main page and then is sent by a function.
This is the function that handles game joining on server side

```
function handleJoinGame(roomName) {
        const room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomName];
}
```

All of this is wrapped inside an

```
io.on('connection', client => {
}
```

The problem is that at this point, before the other user even tries to join, the room is undefined.

```
console.log(room);
```

This gives me undefined.
If I try to actually print out all the rooms, it actually exist, but the method can't find it. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the io.sockets.adapter.rooms returns a Map. Said so, I had to get the room with a key, using

```
const room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomName);
```

I've solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the library for a moment. Conceptually, a `room` is just a group of users. an array of socket connections to whom you broadcast using a for loop. It should come with a `room manager` since you want to have many rooms otherwise you had single room anyway.

Let's assume an object of arrays.

```js
var roomManager = {
  "room12345" : [socket1, socket2, socket5],
  "room76432" : [socket3, socket4],
}
```

and when `socket1` wants to broadcast, you know its room `room12345` so you broadcast to all others in that room.

So really you can implement this logic yourself quite easily.